# Add data from server while serving angular2 app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an angular2 app served from an express server and I need to add some data to the app in the moment in which is served.

At the moment I'm adding the data to the URL and using JavaScript to extract them inside the app, but I would like to hide this data from the user.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Use some kind of placeholder content (like `%%%var%%%`) and replace it in your JS during the serving. This feels rather hacky.
- You're already using express, you could just as well create a proper API endpoint and let the Application communicate with your backend server. This is a little more work, but feels like the proper approach.